# Concerning Paypal and classic API

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have few questions concerning PayPal and Classic API. I have spent the last few days reading and experimenting with 1. Single PayPal Payment using variables and HTML post form. 2. Idem but for recurring/subscription payments. Even though I almost succeed to do most of what I want to accomplish, I still have few questions and grey zone I'd like to debunk.

Here it is:

1. **Is it possible to use classic API, HTML form, PayPal variables and post a request to PayPal/Sandbox AND ONLY use credit card information, without having to log in PayPal or have a PayPal account?** I never succeed and PayPal always block after you hit the PAY button, returning security codes error message or wrong card/account number etc.
   If yes, how and where can I find a real code sample or demo for HTML/MVC-C#?
2. After a make a payment, I receive an invalid response which nothing happens, then, I receive a second IPN response and this one is verified etc. **DO I really need to reply to PayPal/Sandbox to tell them everything is OK? If yes, is there info somewhere or code sample/demo I can see? MY point here is because i receive MANY hits on my IPN and I want to make sure I get the right response, make sure i don't DOUBLE subscribe etc..**
3. **Is there A GOOD MVC or C# IPN code sample somewhere? One I could read and analyse/take to handle most possible scenarios/errors/response code and what to do with them?** not to copy and paste but something reliable I could adapt to my code.
4. I have succeeded to get a response to my IPN with a PayPal account only and **I had to somehow hack security protocol using this instruction --> ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;//SecurityProtocolType.Tls1.2;** and I also had to use ngrok to provide a 'valid' return URL. My question here is, **Do I Need to remove that instruction when I go PROD?**

Thank you so much in advance,

Mart.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, but this is one of the reasons the question got voted down.  You need to sign up for Payments Pro to do credit cards (or you could also use the REST API) and then you would use those specific APIs to process credit cards.  The thing is, depending on what version of Pro you end up with or if you decide to go with REST, the APIs are different, so it's hard for anybody to tell you what to use at this point.
2. Yes, you need to POST back to PayPal to verify that the data actually came from them.  This way you can trash any data where wannabe hackers are posting garbage to your IPN listener or anything else like that going on.

As long as your IPN script completes with a successful 200 response back from your server then PayPal will only send a single IPN.  If you're getting multiples you must have a failure going on, in which case you'll need to [troubleshoot that accordingly](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/).

3. Yes, PayPal provides lots of sample code.  This is another reason your question may have been voted down.  It seems you have not taken the time to look into this stuff yourself.  Go to http://developer.paypal.com and upon reviewing the APIs you'll find they provide [SDKs for different languages](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sdks/).  Each of those comes with samples, and their GitHub repos also include samples.

With a quick Google search you'll find loads of tutorials and samples as well, of course.

Within the developer site you'll also find the [Integration Wizard](https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/), which will let you choose C#, choose the payment integration you want, and it will build it all for you so you can see how it works.

Then, when working on those samples or trying actual code, if you have specific problems / questions, you'd come here and post that specific issue with a code sample that you've tried.  Then people here will be happy to help.

4. TLS 1.2 is a standard requirement for pretty much all web services now because of security vulnerabilities in SSLv3.  If you have "hack" anything (outside of configuration files, maybe) then you're probably doing something unnecessary.  All it would require is to ensure the software stack on your server not only supports TLS 1.2 HTTP requests, but also uses it by default.

Comment: Answer 1. I Mention the use of Classic API. But OK, I guess I will have to go for PRO account when the time is right. I dont want to host ANY financial data on my site and do not want ANY SSL licences either. Answer no 2. OK thank you... Answer 3. I went to Github, Payapl dev, wizard etc. for code sample and I found a functional IPN but its hard to find everything you need... some code sample are out of date and doesn't even work.. just want to find a complete IPN sample...  Answer 4.  I had to add this one line of code with Ngrok... else IE would not go back with IPN response...

Comment: AM I allowed to ask another quick question? I read at least 10 posts about setting the Paypal page_style=your_style_name variable but it seems like it work when i preview the header logo image but when i try it on my site i dont see nothing and i tried to hardcode the hidden field, delete cache, rebuild ans so on but i cant see my logo at all!! i dont even have backgroung color only an image in the paypal header. here is my hidden:    <input type="hidden" name="page_style" value="PayPalGouachePageStyle1"> i even set it as primary or paypal defautl as primary but nothing works! cant see my logo

Comment: It would be easier to setup custom page styles in the PayPal profile.  You can set your colors, banner image, logo image, etc. from there and then that would kick no matter what type of PayPal checkout you're using.

Comment: When using Pro you're going to need an SSL.  No way around that with Pro because you're processing the cards directly through your site, so it needs to be encrypted.  These are only $70/year with most hosting companies, though.

Comment: yes. that's exactly what i did. I configured my custom page style in my paypal sandbox account (business account) and in a preview a can see my logo (ive tried to set it as primary AND not primary AND even add advanced var page_style=mystylename). The thing is that when i run my page in my website it doesnt show the image logo header?! why? i add to my custom button alongside my html paypal variables the hidden page_style and it doesnt work either... I read few times the instructions and followed everything by the letter and it doesnt show logo. I only see it with the paypal sandbox preview..

Comment: If you're setting the custom page in your account profile then don't set anything in the payment request.  Also, if you're seeing it in the sandbox but not live then it sounds like you only configured it in the sandbox account.  It would have to be configured separately for sandbox vs. live.

Comment: well, i configure a button, use it, have to add few extra vars for extra data etc. nothing extravagant and i see it in my preview page of my sandbox account but on my dev site using sandbox as well i dont see the custom page. This is my problem? everything is set in my sandbox account and my dev point to sandbox.. if it wasn't clear there is no live environment involved in this test... look i removed the html page_style var from my form AND set mu style as primary. I dont see it, why? I have 2 style. Paypal default and mine set as primary. I checked every setting pages what do I miss?

Comment: im sorry to add more here but as per Paypal doc, we are suppose to be able to override the page_style ---> Overriding Page Style Settings
Your Primary page style will automatically be applied to all of your payment pages unless you specify otherwise.
you can modify the button's HTML code. Replace the value of the "page_style" variable with the Page Style Name of the style you wish to apply. The next time the button is clicked, its payment pages will appear in the new style. Specifying the "cs" and "image" variables in the button code will also override your Primary page style.

Comment: i just tried a single item which uses entended paypal and i see my logo... why it doenst appear on the classic? maybe it can help orient a bit more my interogation?

Comment: lol i know people here must scratched their heads!! or tired tro hear me but look i found the solution and seriously i doubt you will find this answer NO WHERE on the net cause i did not.... copy/paste this in your form and switch the images URI and your problem is solved. You override the image logo whatever style you have configured!!! well if it doenst work for you! --->     <input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="http://42f9d56f.ngrok.io/Images/imagelogopaypal.png">
    <input type="hidden" name="cpp_logo_image" value="http://42f9d56f.ngrok.io/Images/imagelogopaypal.png">

Comment: Those parameters are clearly outlined in the [PayPal Standard Variable reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/).

Comment: You will have to admit that it is not clear at all which variables you sometimes have to mix with others to have the expected result. ex: as per the paypal doc i have to configure my thing and i did it correctly but i had to test, compare, use extra vars until i find out that i had to add   these two extra vars else my scenario would not give the expected result... no where specified especially if i configure it as a button at the beginning..... SOLUTIONTYPE = "Sole"; LANDINGPAGE = "Billing"; What I mean is maybe more like those advanced variables they lack info or examples..

Comment: SOLUTIONTYPE and LANDINGPAGE belong to the Express Checkout API.  The variables you mentioned previously are for Payments Standard, not Express Checkout.  So again, you're a little bit all over the place which is why you got voted down.  By the way, I'm not one of the people that voted you down.  I've just been trying to give you info about why that happened.  One interesting thing is that when I logged in just now SO looks like they're starting a new "documentation" model where more general info like this would go, so it seems they're finally opening up to this.